# Filter with gt, gte, lt, lte using NodeJs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

I tried to using Filter() function in my NodeJs backend project, this is my function:

```
constructor(query, queryStr ){ 
    this.query = query; 
    this.queryStr = queryStr; } 
filter() { 
    const queryCopy = { ...this.queryStr }; 
    // Removing some fields for category 
    const removeFields = ["keyword", "page", "limit"];    
    removeFields.forEach((key) => delete queryCopy[key]);

    // Filter For Price and Rating

    let queryStr = JSON.stringify(queryCopy);
    queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gt|gte|lt|lte)\b/g, (key) => `$${key}`);

    this.query = this.query.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));
    console.log(queryStr)
    
    return this;
  }
```

I am using postman to send request with the URL:
`http://localhost:4000/api/v1/products?price%5Blt%5D=2000&price%5Bgte%5D=1200`

It didn't send any product, although I have a product with price=1200 in database, and another problem is when I log my (queryStr), it look like that:
`{"price\[$lt\]":"2000","price\[$gte\]":"1200"}`

What I expected is:
`{"price":{\[$lt\]":"2000","\[$gte\]":"1200"}}`

I think it is main reason to my problem, please help me.

Comment: the URL is: http://localhost:4000/api/v1/products?price[lt]=2000&price[gte]=1200

Comment: Your expected MongoDB query is invalid, the valid one should be: `{"price":{ $lt: 2000, $gte: 1200 }}`. The operator shouldn't be wrapped with square bracket, and the amount should be in number but not string.

Comment: Nobody is able to access **your** `localhost`

Comment: Are you using mongoose or native Node MongoDB client? If you are using mongoose you can just request `http://localhost:4000/api/v1/products?price[$lt]=2000&price[$gte]=1200` then `req.query` will be in the format `{ price: { '$lt': '2000', '$gte': '1200' } ` and mongoose will cast the strings `'2000'` and `'1200'` to numbers automatically if the `price` is defined as `Number` in your schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = {'price[lt]': 2000, 'price[gte]': 1200, 'other': 'parameters'};

console.log(a); // { 'price[lt]': 2000, 'price[gte]': 1200 }

let finalObject = {};
for (const i of Object.keys(a)) {
    const key = i.match(/(price|amount)/)?.shift(); // modify your key params here ex: price, amount etc..
    const expr = i.match(/\b(gt|gte|lt|lte)\b/)?.shift();
    if (key && expr) {
        if (finalObject[key]) Object.assign(finalObject[key], { [`[$${expr}]`]: a[i] });
        else Object.assign(finalObject, { [key]: { [`[$${expr}]`]: a[i] }});
    } else Object.assign(finalObject, { [i]: a[i] });
}
console.log('finalObject...', finalObject); // {"price":{"[$lt]":2000,"[$gte]":1200},'other':'parameters'}
```